# How to search for a key in the registry with wildcards in a batch or VBScript?

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file, registry

I need to make a batch or a VBScript, which uninstalls every versions of Mozilla Firefox. In the registry there is a key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Mozilla Firefox (Version).
```

`Version` has a value the installed Firefox Versions. And under this key there is an entry `UninstallString`. I need read somehow this value. The problem is, that the Version is a variable. So if Mozilla Firefox 1.0.1 is isntalled then the key will look like :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Mozilla Firefox (1.0.1).
```

If 2.0.2 is installed, then the key will look like:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Mozilla Firefox (2.0.2).
```

But i don't know which version is installed. So how can i read this key (and the Uninstall value) without knowing which version is installed?
Could someone help me in this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use a batch wildcard * for the version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
const REG_PATH = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
const FOX_MASK = "Mozilla Firefox*"

dim re: set re = New RegExp
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = FOX_MASK

dim oReg: set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
oReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REG_PATH, arrSubKeys

dim strValue
for each subkey In arrSubKeys
    if re.test(subkey) then
       oReg.GetExpandedStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REG_PATH & subkey, "UninstallString", strValue
       WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Version: " & subkey
       WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Uninstaller: " & strValue
    end if
next
```

For me outputs:

`Version: Mozilla Firefox 7.0 (x86 en-GB)`

**Uninstaller:** C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe

(Note this is different from your pattern)